# Shared mortgage ownership

Tags: mortgage

I took the mortgage 7 years ago with the help of a friend in order to be approved. Now my financial situation is good and I would to take him off the mortgage and put myself and my wife on the mortgage. What's the best way to do it , excepting refinancing?

Comment: What country, and did you talk to your bank[mortgage provider]. It may be as simple as filling in few forms.

Comment: There are two different issues: (i) who are the owners of the property as recorded on the property rolls and how do they own the property, and (ii) who are the mortgagees. "Taking my friend off the mortgage" does not change who _owns_ the property if land records show you and your friend as co-owners of the property; the two of you also need to file a deed transferring your friend's ownership interest to you and your wife. In short, you need to provide more details about such matters (as well as those requested by Dheer) in order to get an answer that will be useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

A cosigner of a loan is liable if you miss payments. The friend guaranteed your ability to pay for the life of the loan. 
If the bank has sold the mortgage (into the convoluted world of CMOs, collateralized mortgage obligations) the original bank doesn't hold the mortgage and cannot change the terms. If it's held locally, you need to ask the bank. You have a track record of paying and with your wife, income they can verify, and they may be willing to work with you.

But, let's look at the numbers for a refi-  The 30 year fixed rate in 2006 was over 6%. Let me do some math - Starting with $100K, 6%, and a payment of $600, 7 years later you'd owe $89,640. A new 30 year mortgage at 4.5% would give you a $454 payment, or go 15 yrs and the payment is $686, letting you finish the mortgage 8 years sooner. Scale the numbers X fold based on the original mortgage amount. Note - if you kept the same 23 years remaining, it drops to $522, a $78/mo savings per $100K of original loan.  (Yes, US rates)

Comment: Perhaps you should address the issue of ownership of the property also. If I were a co-signer on the mortgage and also a co-owner of the property, I would be happy to relinquish the liability for keeping up the mortgage payments without relinquishing ownership of the property as well.

Comment: The OP needs to clarify whether the friend actually had any ownership. I read the question to mean it was cosigning to guarantee the loan only.

Comment: That is why I asked for clarification in a comment on the main question before composing an answer. It is also one thing to be a co-signer in the sense of guaranteeing payment if the mortgagee defaults (sort of like PMI provided by the OP's friend) and a joint mortgagee, responsible for the monthly payments month in and month out, with the mortgage being issued (in the joint name of the OP and friend) based on the total creditworthiness of the OP and the friend, and the friend possibly contributing to part of the downpayment and/or the monthly payments.